# trying to access keys and values from a nested json - javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a nested json which looks like this:

```
{'services': 
    {
        'serviceA': 'OptionA',
        'serviceB': 'OptionB',
        'serviceC': null
    },
'AttributeB': 'ValueB',
'AttributeC': 'ValueC'
}
```

I would like to render nested json (services) in a tabular format like this:

services     option
serviceA     OptionA
serviceB     OptionB
serviceC

I was trying something like this:

```
var myJSONObject =  {'services': 
        {
            'serviceA': 'OptionA',
            'serviceB': 'OptionB',
            'serviceC': null
        },
    'AttributeB': 'ValueB',
    'AttributeC': 'ValueC'
    };

for(var i = 0; i < myJSONObject.services.length; i++)
{
    var product = myJSONObject.services[i];
    alert(product.key);
    alert(product.value);
}
```

This doesn't seem to help. I am guessing I am retrieving the object in an incorrect manner. Can somebody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: When you type product.key, are you actually typing product.AttributeB?
Also, use console.log() to see what the values are of things you're printing.

Comment: You are iterating over an object but using the array syntax. Use the `for in` loop to iterate over the object instead of `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

`services` is an object and you need to iterate over its properties. For that you can try following

```
var myJSONObject =  {'services': 
        {
            'serviceA': 'OptionA',
            'serviceB': 'OptionB',
            'serviceC': null
        },
    'AttributeB': 'ValueB',
    'AttributeC': 'ValueC'
    };

for(var key in myJSONObject.services)
{
    alert(key);
    alert(myJSONObject.services[key]);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked 100%. I am a bit new to nested JSON and properties! Thank you again @nikhil

Comment: @chrisrhyno2003 - Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

@nikhil's answer works but you might want to check for properties using `hasOwnProperty` also to be on the safe side.

```
let services = myJSONObject.services
for(let key in services)
{
   if(services.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     console.log(key);
     console.log(services[key]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `Object.keys` and `Array.forEach` functions:

```
var services = myJSONObject['services'];
Object.keys(services).forEach((key) => console.log(key + ' : '+ (services[key] || "")));
```

The output:

```
serviceA : OptionA
serviceB : OptionB
serviceC :
```